# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error when running the program. I input the name and click the login button and the page will be directed to the the new page which is the index.html file and i get the error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in my first JS file.

Here is my 1st JS file:

```
var name = '';
const login = document.querySelector('.logButton');


login.addEventListener('click', () =>{
name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
});
```

and here is the body of the HTML file of this JS file

```
<div class = loginPage>
<input type = 'text' placeholder= 'Username' class = names></input> <a href = '../index.html'><button class = logButton> Login</button></a>
</div>
```

heres the 2nd JS file of the index.html

```
const now = new Date();
const hour = now.getHours();
const morning = " ";
const night = " ";
const div = document.querySelector('.page_1_body');

function print(docu){
  div.innerHTML = "<h1> <a href = 'Page_2/page2.html'>" + docu +"</a>";
}

function dayrnight(name){
if ( hour <= 24 && hour < 18 ){
  const morning = "<h1> Good Day " + name + " !</h1>";
  print(morning);
} else {
  const night = "<h1>Good evening " + name + " !</h1>";
  print(night);
}
}

dayrnight(name);
```

here is the index.html file

```
<body>
    <div class = page_1_body>
    </div>

<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src = "Login_page/Login.js"></script>
</body>
```

I posted the codes so it can help to solve my problem. thank you!

Comment: Try putting the quotes around the class attributes value in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing mistakes in your `class` attributes for `class = loginPage`, `class = names` and `class = logButton`. You are not putting your class name in double quotes and second is that your `class=names` should be `class=name`.

Check the below code:

Change this:

```
<div class = loginPage>
<input type = 'text' placeholder= 'Username' class = names></input> <a href = '../index.html'><button class = logButton> Login</button></a>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class ="loginPage">
<input type = 'text' placeholder= 'Username' class ="name"></input> <a href = '../index.html'><button class="logButton"> Login</button></a>
</div>
```

Please read about CSS class attribute more here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp

Answer (score 1):

You missed wrapping the `logButton` `class` into quotes. Fix it like this:

```
<button class = "logButton">
```

Also, you will need to make sure that the `button`'s HTML was already generated when you try to load it, so wrap

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //Your code here
}
```

around your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file, you should add double quotes to wrap the classes names you want to add to your element, like this:

```
<div class = loginPage>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="names"></input> <a href="../index.html"><button class="logButton"> Login</button></a>
</div>
```